# Replace values based on column of column names

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a large dataframe (>1000 rows) of measurements. One of the columns is Fails (type str) that contains the columns for which the measurement failed. Whether the measurement fails isn't solely based on the value so I can't just replace all negative values for example, which is why there is a Fails column

```
Cd  Sn  Sb   Zn  Fails 
-1  -2  0.0  4   Cd Sn Sb
-2  0.0 -1   5   Cd Sn Sb
-3  -3  -2   6   Cd Sn Sb 
 1   2   3   4   Zn
```

If the element failed I need to replace the measurement with nan. So for every row in the df, I need to set df.loc[row,col]=nan if the col is in Fails.

```
Cd  Sn    Sb   Zn  Fails 
nan  nan  nan  4   Cd Sn Sb
nan  nan  nan  5   Cd Sn Sb
nan  nan  nan  6   Cd Sn Sb 
1    2    3   nan  Zn
```

What is a efficient way of doing this?

Edit:

I tried to use a simple example above. There's many more columns in the df. There's actually 29 different elements. This is what the portion of interest looks like

```
data.iloc[:,5:34]
Out[45]: 
             Se          As   Ga   Ni  ...         Tl          Pb         U   Ir
0     19.026755    3.290577  0.0  0.0  ...   0.619604    4.674604  0.030976  0.0
1     35.682812   55.108543  0.0  0.0  ...   4.217798   25.213694  0.216073  0.0
2     93.600473  187.171588  0.0  0.0  ...  12.480773   74.187307  0.647617  0.0
3    229.575678  560.092296  0.0  0.0  ...  37.041994  261.348135  1.926765  0.0
4     56.337625   14.344270  0.0  0.0  ...   0.375804    0.926559  0.004466  0.0
..          ...         ...  ...  ...  ...        ...         ...       ...  ...
871         NaN         NaN  NaN  NaN  ...        NaN         NaN       NaN  NaN

data["Fails"]
Out[50]: 
0      Cd Sn Sb Cu Zn
1      Cd Sn Sb Cu Zn
2      Cd Sn Sb Cu Zn
3      Cd Sn Sb Cu Zn
4      Cd Sn Sb Cu Zn

871
```

When I try the solutions suggested I am getting more nans than I should

```
     Se  As  Ga  Ni         Mn  ...  Tl  Pb         U  Ir
0   NaN NaN NaN NaN   0.715142  ... NaN NaN  0.030976 NaN  
1   NaN NaN NaN NaN   2.295966  ... NaN NaN  0.216073 NaN  
2   NaN NaN NaN NaN   6.654716  ... NaN NaN  0.647617 NaN  
3   NaN NaN NaN NaN  20.567433  ... NaN NaN  1.926765 NaN  
4   NaN NaN NaN NaN   0.285542  ... NaN NaN  0.004466 NaN  
..   ..  ..  ..  ..        ...  ...  ..  ..       ...  ..  
871 NaN NaN NaN NaN        NaN  ... NaN NaN       NaN NaN
```

In the first couple of rows only Cd,Sn,Sb,Cu and Zn should be set to nan and everything else should be kept as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my approach:

```
rep_cols = ['Cd','Sn','Sb','Cu','Zn']
s = df.Fails.str.split(expand=True).stack().reset_index(name='col')

df.loc[:, rep_cols] = df.mask(s.pivot('level_0', 'col', 'level_1').notnull())
```

Output:

```
    Cd   Sn   Sb   Zn     Fails
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  4.0  Cd Sn Sb
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  5.0  Cd Sn Sb
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  6.0  Cd Sn Sb
3  1.0  2.0  3.0  NaN        Zn
```

Comment: thanks. I ended up doing it a slightly different way but your comment helped me figure out what i needed to fix

Answer (score 0):

IIUC we use `get_dummies`

```
df=df.mask(df.Fails.str.get_dummies(' ').astype(bool)).assign(Fails=df.Fails)
df
    Cd   Sn   Sb   Zn     Fails
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  4.0  Cd Sn Sb
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  5.0  Cd Sn Sb
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  6.0  Cd Sn Sb
3  1.0  2.0  3.0  NaN        Zn
```